Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnihdf5 in java.library.path
The error is:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnihdf5 in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni, /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu, /usr/lib/jni, /lib, /usr/lib]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2678)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1890)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:1832)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1423)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1234)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1210)
    at org.bytedeco.hdf5.global.hdf5.<clinit>(hdf5.java:14)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1289)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1234)
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1226)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.Hdf5Archive.<clinit>(Hdf5Archive.java:56)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.utils.KerasModelBuilder.modelHdf5Filename(KerasModelBuilder.java:229)
    at org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.KerasModelImport.importKerasSequentialModelAndWeights(KerasModelImport.java:217)
    at KerasModelInference$.main(KerasModelLoader.scala:14)
    at KerasModelInference.main(KerasModelLoader.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not find jnihdf5 in class, module, and library paths.
    at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:1799)
    ... 14 more

I tried installing libhdf5-dev.
However, I couldn't find jnihdf5 anywhere in my system. I checked .javacpp/cache/hdf5-1.12.1-1.5.7-linux-x86_64.jar/org/bytedeco/hdf5/linux-x86_64, but I could find only 'libjnihdf5.so'
May I know where to find or how can I get it?
My program is in scala. I'm trying to load .h5 file.
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.modelimport.keras.KerasModelImport
import org.deeplearning4j.nn.multilayer.MultiLayerNetwork
...
...

val model: MultiLayerNetwork = KerasModelImport.importKerasSequentialModelAndWeights(modelPath)

The following are the dependencies added in my program:
deeplearning4j-modelimport-1.0.0-M2.1
deeplearning4j-core-1.0.0-M2.1
deeplearning4j-nn-1.0.0-M2.1
nd4j-api-1.0.0-M2.1.jar
nd4j-commom-1.0.0.-M2.1.jar
hdf5-1.14.3-1.5.10.jar
hdf5-platform-1.14.3-1.5.0
javacpp-1.5.10.jar
javacpp-platform-1.5.10.jar
I'm new to this field. Any help is appreciated.

Please try again with 1.14.3-1.5.10
